# Windows Short Names Confusing Git

Tags: git, configuration, windows-7, centos, naming

I am using Git, and observing the following oddness: a file that hasn't been changed is showing as being renamed. Ex:

```
rename from path/to/file/filename.txt
rename to path/to/file/FILENA~1.txt
```

Another example:

```
rename from another/path/file.longext
rename to another/path/FILE~2.LON
```

Last example:

```
rename from folder/path/file.csv
rename to folder/PATH~2/file.csv
```

I was just looking around the repo and got [nerd sniped](https://xkcd.com/356/) by the differences in behavior between Windows and Linux.

The git repo is on an NFS network drive and is mounted in both a Linux (CentOS) VM and a Windows 7 VM. Each VM has its own installation of Git. On Linux , Git is showing no changes. On Windows 7, Git is showing >800 changes. Most of the changes are like the examples above. Upon further investigation, I found that there were multiple files/folders *with the same spelling but different case* in the repo. Looking at Windows for the last example, I see this in directory `folder`:

```
X:\nfs_mount\repo\folder>dir
 Volume in drive X is name
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX

 Directory of X:\nfs_mount\repo\folder

xx/xx/xxxx xx:xx AM    <DIR>          .
xx/xx/xxxx xx:xx AM    <DIR>          ..
xx/xx/xxxx xx:xx AM    <DIR>          PATH
xx/xx/xxxx xx:xx AM    <DIR>          PATH~1
```

And this is what I see in the same location from Linux:

```
fqdn.domain.com:/some/location/repo/folder$ ls -l
total xx
drwxr-xr-x 3 username compname 4096 XXX xx xx:xx path/
drwxr-xr-x 3 username compname 4096 XXX xx xx:xx PATH/
```

My problem is the folders whose names have the same spelling but different casing. Given that this is a large repo, this problem has more than 400 manifestations in various locations, and I can't (not allowed to) change all these locations, is there a way I can make Git on windows realize that these aren't actually changes? I am aware that renaming everything on Linux would fix this, but that solution isn't available to me.

I am looking for either a git configuration setting I can change, or a windows settings. The change must be something I can apply to my local repo/VMs and will not affect the remote repo or change the repo in any way. The version of git on Windows 7 is `git version 2.13.2.windows.1`, installed using Git Extensions.

Comment: I avoid Windows for many reasons, and this is one of them. :-) I doubt there's any way to handle this at all in Git itself. You will need some sort of lower-level handler (below / before the Windows `PATH~1` substitution occurs) that synthesizes a name that Windows can deal with, or some way of turning off case-folding in Windows, if that's even possible. (It is on MacOS but it's a file-system-level setting.)

Comment: @torek, I can, and do, use the Linux VM as the main way of interacting with Git. As I said, I saw this and got nerd sniped, and the only way I know of to fix it doesn't work here. Even if this isn't possible, then I will have learned that it isn't possible.

Comment: Something that's kind of missing, in Git, that would be useful here is a name-mapper: some way of saying *I know the file system claims that the file is named A.EXT but please pretend instead that it's named foo.longext*. If that existed, you could build the solution out of it.

Comment: @torek, Something like GDB's path substitution, you mean? That would be nice. While Googling this, I came across several other people that had similar issues, which helped me figure out what was going on here. Fixes for those were all "change the repo". But that has its own problems when talking about a large team with different dev environments. I've also seen this happen by accident when 2 people create the same file independently. A substitution feature for Git would need to allow "sub *this* for *that* and default to *this*".

Comment: Have you tried cloning the repository to the local windows filesystem? It should be handling case-insensitivity issues.

Comment: Probably you could set `core.ignoreCase` to true remotely and re-checkout it at Linux, so that everybody would work with case-insensitive checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Here is unusual situation: it is checked out to Linux case-sensitive filesystem, and then mapped live in some weird way to Windows filesystem. I'm not sure if you can do much at that remote checkout. It is additionally complicated by the fact that it shares the index file with Linux, so getting too far with windows awareness could break accessing the repository at Linux side.

What you can do is to clone it locally, then git should be able to handle directories with different cases:

```
git clone -s REMOTE_LOCATION LOCAL_LOCATION
```

The -s flag would let you avoid copying all git data. Then you can use the data, or edit something, commit and push back. It is better to perform modification of working tree files through Linux tools.

PS: at windows-only checkout of such repositories is supported, I have checked it:

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    Dir/file2
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    dir/file
```

This is checked out properly with single "dir" subdirectory and there are no changes in git status